# Safety - Can created objects have unknown properties?

Tags: javascript

I've subscribed to the common idiom:

```
for(var key in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnPropery(key)){ 
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

but if I do something like:

```
var obj = {a: 'a', b: 'b'};
```

Do I need to worry about `obj` having properties other than "a" and "b" when I loop?

Or is the above idiom primarily for objects that you the developer did not create?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically yes, the `Object.prototype` can be modified (for a good or bad reason). These show up as enumerable properties (which will show up while enumerating).

When the `Object.prototype` is modified, it affects all instances of objects, so your `obj` is included in that. For example, if some other script/library executes this:

```
Object.prototype.keyLength = function () {
    var count = 0;
    for (var key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) count++;
    }
    return count;
};
```

Then this will be the results of iterating over your `obj` (without using `hasOwnProperty`):

```
a
b
keyLength
```

(not necessarily in that order)

If you used `hasOwnProperty`, you'd only see "a" and "b".

It's not ideal to modify the `Object` prototype (for several reasons), but a "safer" way to do so is with `Object.defineProperty` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty . You are able to describe it as enumerable or not. It's a newer method, so it's not globally available in browsers. Of course, you can't force other libraries to use this as you don't have control over them. But if you can, it's advisable for your own use.

Your use of `hasOwnProperty` is to make sure the key you're looking at is an actual property and not a property on the prototype chain and isn't enumerable. Which does solve the `prototype` "problem". Just for reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: If I'm running in my own IIFE, like most libraries, is it possible for another library to modify the Object.prototype that I use?

Comment: if he does hasownproperty() does it still affect him?

Comment: @theshadowmonkey No, but I think the OP was wondering if the `hasOwnProperty` is necessary. That's a good point though, I'll just add that in

Comment: This is true, but unless you're building a library you have control over Object.prototype being modified (by your own code or a third party you added). It bothers me seeing checks for own properties all over the code when it isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: @livingston_mechanical if it is globally available anyone can modify I suppose

Comment: @livingston_mechanical And the IIFE makes no difference. You create your object with `{}`, which means it is an `Object`. `obj` will use the `Object` prototype. Since `Object` is simply "global", it's very possible for anything to modify it.

Comment: @livingston_mechanical Right, but IIFEs aren't made to "shield" built-in stuff. It's to "shield" your specific code

Comment: @bfavaretto But who's to say any 3rd party code won't modify `Object`? I like to assume other code won't, but there's no guarantee or way to find out unless you use `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: Well for one you'll see the something break, and raise a suspect on Object.prototype being modified. I actually agree with your answer, my comment is sort of a rant about people being overzealous. Consider for example if some 3rd party code does `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = function() { return true; }`. Now what? The only way out would be to get a clean Object.prototype from an iframe. Does this mean we should always get a clean prototype and only use that? I hope not.

Comment: I think it should be accepted that this exposure of the internals...i.e. the ability to modify Object.prototype is a design flaw in the language...I'm surprised it is not mentioned in JavaScript, The Good Parts as a flaw....instead I think he actually builds off the prototype.

Comment: @bfavaretto That's funny you say all that - I've been thinking about that lately. I often catch myself checking for too much and worry too much. It's also interesting you mentioned you could get a fresh `Object.prototype` from an iframe - I never thought of that.

Comment: @livingston_mechanical Well, I'm not sure it's a flaw, and I don't think many people will agree with you...although some will, and some will about certain points. It's an interesting subject, and very debatable, and I don't know what I think of it :)

Comment: @livingston_mechanical Shuttles can crash too! :)

Comment: @Ian Yep, the iframe thing is really interesting. I'm not sure if there are limitations, though. Here is a simple test if you want to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/UuPaD/.

Comment: @bfavaretto Cool, thanks for setting it up. Yeah, the only "limitation" I can think of is `cleanPrototype instanceof Object` is false (not sure if that's obvious to you or not). I don't know what that would affect, but I saw that the other day on here.

Comment: @livingston_mechanical I'm not sure what you mean. What do you find to be true?

Comment: @livingston_mechanical Ahh okay, haha. Does everything make sense? Or do you need any more help with it?